# AJAX post method, sometimes is triggered on page loading and sometimes not

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a strange problem with AJAX, I'm returning a map of objects using AJAX POST method on page loading.

I'm debugging the process, sometimes the method is called, and the Java Servlet runs, sometimes not.

I have included the JS import properly, other jQuery calls are working fine.

I tried with different explorers.

I used GET method instead, but still the same.

Did anyone face the same problem before? Thanks

My code:

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// here there is another ajax servlet call, and it's working fine all time.

$.get("ServletName", function(responseJson) {      

//do some action

});
});
```

Servlet:

```
package packageName; //I keep it like that without a subfolder name that contains the servlets, doing so not to import the java classes located in the original package...would this be the problem?

@WebServlet(name = "ServletName", urlPatterns = {"/ServletName"})

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

Map<Integer, ClassName> objectsTree = new TreeMap<>();        
//adding objects to the map

    String mapString = new Gson().toJson(objectsTree);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(mapString);
    }
```

I have doubts about my files location, my JSP file is located under "root\web\"
My selvlets are located root\src\java\packageName\servlets\

But still. all servlets are called and no problem, but only this call is not reaching all the time...if I keep running the debugger again and again, it will work at some try.

Comment: `triggered on page loading` - what exactly is the trigger you are using here?

Comment: Can you include the relevant code? Its hard to debug without code...

Comment: sorry I just noticed someone replied...I didn't get emails notification

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my mistake, my servlets are located in a subfolder after the Java classes root. yet, I kept the declaration of the servlets' package referring to the same as the Java classes root instead of adding the subfolder name to the package declaration.

```
package packageName;
```

it should have been

```
package packageName.servlets;
```

the only thing made me keep it this way, that things seemed ok with many aspects, but eventually I faced problems because of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your code is not waiting for the document to be ready. But it's hard to know without seeing your code.

Comment: sorry I just noticed someone replied...I didn't get emails notification
I added my code if you would like to check....thank you

Comment: I added a button and tried to trigger it on button click after thepage is loaded...same problem...sometimes it was working, sometimes not

Comment: I would suggest inspecting the list of Ajax requests in the browsers web inspector. Is the request happening but failing?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that to be honest...I'll try to look it up..thank you

Comment: Use can use Google Chrome, Safari, or Firefox. Here is the Chrome documentation for the "Network" tab: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/workspace/setup-devtools#network-panel-monitor-network-performance

Comment: I think I found my mistake, my servlets are located in a subfolder after the Java classes root. yet, I kept the declaration of its packages referring to the Java classes root instead of adding the subfolder name to the package declaration.

the only thing made me keep it this way, that things seemed ok, but eventually I faced problems because of that.

Thanks for the help Andrew, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear you found your solution!